# Cleaning up scraped Nokogiri output

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, web-scraping

The output of what I'm scraping leaves me with this:

```
<li><img class="static" src="pic.jpg"><span id="dynamic1" class="the text">I like turtles</span></li>
<li><img class="static" src="pic.jpg"><span id="dynamic2" class="the text">I like bears</span></li>
<li><img class="static" src="pic.jpg"><span id="dynamic3" class="the text">I like ruby</span></li>
<li><img class="static" src="pic.jpg"><span id="dynamic4" class="the text">I like oranges</span></li>
<li><img class="static" src="pic.jpg"><span id="dynamic5" class="the text">I like keyboards</span></li>
<li><img class="static" src="pic.jpg"><span id="dynamic6" class="the text">I like movies</span></li>
<li><img class="static" src="pic.jpg"><span id="dynamic7" class="the text">I like Android</span></li>
<li><img class="static" src="pic.jpg"><span id="dynamic8" class="the text">I like Mac</span></li>
<li><img class="static" src="pic.jpg"><span id="dynamic9" class="the text">I like music</span></li>
<li><img class="static" src="pic.jpg"><span id="dynamic10" class="the text">I like boats</span></li>
```

There is about 100 lines of this with the span class being different each time, and the "I like turtles" part being different each time.

Ideally, I only want the "I like turtles" part of each line. Is there a way to get this?

Example 10 lines

Comment: There is a way; might help if you post 10 of those hundred lines as we can determine the right pattern...

Comment: is it right to assume your `span`, regardless of the `class`, always  follows (like in `following-sibling`) the `img` and is a child to the `li`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you end up with a bunch of HTML like this:

```
<ul>
    <li><img ...><span ...>I want this text</span></li>
    <li><img ...><span ...>I want this text</span></li>
    ...
</ul>
```

Then you can extract the `<li>`s and then extract the text from each `<li>` while ignoring the tags inside it:

```
texts_you_want = doc.css('li').map(&:text)
```

That will ignore the `<img>` and the `<span>` elements inside the `<li>`s and no one needs to care about what classes they happen to have.

Comment: Thanks so much. I'm going to have to read up on the map method.

Answer (score 2):

> Following "convention" from the answer with the `doc.css()`.

Nokogiri allows you to run XPath on the result of `Nokogiri::HTML` as if it was a well formed XML:

```
text_you_want = doc.xpath("//li/span").map(&:text)
```

p.s. The reason I did `//` and not the root `/` is because if you parse your scraping leftovers with `Nokogiri::HTML` it will wrap it into the `<html><body>` for you. Writing the XPath to your fragment as `/html/body/li/span` looks kind of awkward :)

Comment: could you please explain how "map(&:text)" works in brief, or any pointers about it, "&:" seems interesting, how it works? it does not seem to be a standard operator, looks like a magic.

Comment: @AmolPujari, google "symbol to proc". you will find and learn much more than I can say in a comment field.

Comment: @AmolPujari: In short, `x.map(&:m)` is shorthand for `x.map { |o| o.m }`, it nicely removes the block and variable noise and allows you to get straight to the point.